# Floating Divs, adjust height to the bigger one

Tags: html, css, css-float

#### My problem:

I want to make my floated divs adapt its `height` to the bigger one. I tried many things like setting the height of `.item` to 100% but that didn't work.

Do I really have to set `.row` display to table or  is there any other solution for such a simple problem? Thanks for your help.

```css
.item {
  background-color: lightblue; 
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="item left">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"" />
      </div>
      <div class="item right">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"" />
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Please ignore the lorempixel images, I just included them for demonstrating my problem</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this using CSS on floated elements.
But this easily achievable with jQuery.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsv55hdk/)

Basically, it uses Paul Irish's max height snippet.

```
$.fn.setAllToMaxHeight = function(){
return this.height( Math.max.apply(this, $.map( this , function(e){ return $(e).height() }) ) );
}

$('.item').setAllToMaxHeight();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer though I am not willing to use javascript for such problems.

Comment: In the end I used your script, because a) it's just a little script b) all other solutions didn't fit my needs. Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

What about clear after floating elements, eg. like this:

```
.row {overflow: hidden}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99tm9zxg/

Sure, it doesn´t put  to shorter element height of the higher one, but you don´t need that. In real there is not necessary to have both element of the same height.

Comment: If I wouldn't need it I wouldn't have asked the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Fine, can you tell me why you need to have both elements of the same height? I´m really interesting in, because I´ve never needed to use that. thanks.

Comment: I have a two column layout that would simply just look ugly if the divs don't have the same height as their neighbour.

Comment: You can solve that using background on their parents (.row in this case) which will simulate the same height. It´s using without need of 100kB jQuery code :-) Loading jQuery for this is so expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is using `table-cell`:

```
.item {
  background-color: lightblue; 
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**<kbd>Check the Snippet Below</kbd>**

```css
.item
{
  background-color: lightblue; 
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="item right">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I space the cells exactly 50px (margin-left)? border-spacing is awful because it corrupts my layout, I need a setting that equals margin-left.